# Spring @Value adding Validation less than

Tags: java, spring

I using the following property  value injection. How I can add a less than validation to this operation.
I mean I want to set a validation the `user.maxpassiveday` property value has not to be less than 100 lets say.

```
  @Value("${user.maxpassiveday}")
   int maxpassiveday;
```

Using Spring 3.1.1 version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use @Value on setter method:

```
int maxpassiveday;

@Value("${user.maxpassiveday}")
public void setMaxPassiveDay(final String maxpassiveday) {
   int tmp = Integer.parseInt(maxpassiveday);
   if (tmp < 100) {
      this.maxpassiveday = tmp;
   }
}
```